# Memory problem with gedit

Tags: gedit

I found that as a gedit session runs longer, the more memory it takes, regardless of how small the sizes of the text files opened in the session are. So is it normal or a memory leak problem?

For example, I now open 16 text files, each about 1~2KB, but the memory gedit takes is 100Mib.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a memory leak.  It could also be creating an undo storage area or any number of other minor things that no one thinks of when using a text editor, like syntax highlighting by extension for example.  If you want a really low memory profile go for vim or nano.  If you want to accept the impact of features, then go for something with a gui.